# Credible interval for a quantile from log-normally distributed data

Tags: bayesian, quantiles, lognormal-distribution, credible-interval

Both reviewers of my latest article suggested better to work with credible intervals instead confidence intervals. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Bayesian statistics. Until today, I was (obviously) more in the frequentist world, why I feel completely lost how I can obtain credible intervals from my data. After I have read a lot, I would say that I have understand the general difference between both interval types. But I do not see how I can get credible intervals.

My situation: I have log-normally distributed data from an experiment. From these data, I wish to estimate distribution parameters $\tilde{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}$, so that I can use the estimates to calculate quantiles with the inverted CDF (e.g., for $q=0.75$). My question now is, how can I calculate the credible interval $[ x^L_q, x^U_q ]$ for $x_q$? Based on the credible interval, I will argue that the unobservable quantile $x_q$ falls with a particular probability (here 95%) within this interval.

Since I am not an expert in statistics I do not even know if my question makes sense. I hope that someone can push me into the right direction or give me some advice how to start.

Comment: Can you describe your experiment and sample size?  Can you give us more context on the review?  Why do the reviewers think this?  If they just replied "Use credible intervals" I think it would be appropriate to say "No" with reasons supporting your frequentist analysis (assuming it was done well).

Comment: 1. "I feel completely lost how I can obtain credible intervals from my data" ... presumably you would be obtaining intervals for parameters/functions of parameters rather than data. The remainder of your post seems to bear that out.  $\,$ 2. "I have log-normally distributed data from an experiment." -- how can you know it's actually lognormal? Presumably you mean instead that you have data that you have chosen to use a lognormal model for.  That's fine.  $\,$ 3. You need a prior on your parameters. Calculation of a posterior from there should be relatively routine.

Comment: 4. Depending on the type of interval you want to form, you might consider working with the log of the data (and hence quantiles).  For example if you wanted a symmetric interval (symmetric in terms of probability in the tails),  that would work. A HPD interval would be best to stick with the original scale.

Comment: @DemetriPananos: I have measured pain-onset thresholds on 40 human subjects. From the data, I have developed force-displacement curves for each body locations tested. Around these curves, I would like to lie a "corridor" that indicates the space in which the true (but unknown) force-displacement curve can lie. The reviewers suggested that a credible corridor would better fit to what try to express. From what I've learned, their suggestion makes sense to me.

Comment: @Glen_b: 1) Correct. 2) Yes, I have chosen a log-normal model because it matches my data best. 3) Could the prior a log-normal PDF with parameters from a similar study? The posterior is then the updated prior that was produced with my data from the experiments, right? 4) I've already thought about this since it enables me to work with a normal distribution. Symmetric interval is just fine for my purpose.

Comment: From your description, I don't see the benefit of using credible intervals over confidence intervals.  Are similars studies *very* informative, with large samples?  If not, it might mean biasing your estimates with no good reason.  Additionally, are you interested in bands containing the entire curve?  If so neither confidence nor credible intervals are the right tool.

Comment: "Could the prior a log-normal PDF with parameters from a similar study?" ---  you're not putting a prior on the *data*,  You're expressing your beliefs about possible parameter values of the model. That can incorporate information from other studies if you wish, though it's important to keep in mind that underlying parameters won't generally be the same across studies; the question is how different might the parameters of some model be here and how you want to incorporate the various kinds of uncertainty into your prior.

Comment: @DemetriPananos: Yes, I am interested in bands containing the entire force-displacement curve. The purpose of the band is to express the range of uncertainty or a measure for the credibility of the curve. Of course, I can tie the curve to the mean and use the STD to produce bands around the curve. But I want to tie my curve to a specific quantile (i.e. q=0.75). For this curve, I want draw bands to express its uncertainty. What do you have in mind to use instead of credible intervals?

Comment: @Glen_b: I think I have understood the general concept. Let's say I neglect similar studies and use instead a flat prior (proportional to 1). Assuming data from a normal distribution and the flat prior, confidence interval and credible interval will be the same, correct? In this case, is it eligible to consider my confidence intervals as credible intervals and enable me to say "from a Bayesian viewpoint" the correct curve lies within the interval curves with a probabilit of 95%? Or am I on the wrong track here?

Comment: That question is (in various forms) asked and answered multiple times on site. Try a few searches in the search bar, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=confidence+interval+credible ... my aim with the comment on priors was to help you correct the mistaken premise about the prior in your present question (via an edit), which would enable a more focused question and hopefully better answers. If this new question is what you were trying to ask, see what the posts on this topic cover and then if there's still some unanswered aspect of what you needed, edit the question.